# Game Center disconnection check flaw

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I have a game center real time multiplayer application, and when checking when a player has disconnected there is an exploit. I have this code:

```
func match(match: GKMatch!, player player: GKPlayer!, didChangeConnectionState state: GKPlayerConnectionState){
    println("called")
    if(state==GKPlayerConnectionState.StateConnected){
        println("connected")
    }
    if(state==GKPlayerConnectionState.StateDisconnected){
        println("Disconnected")
    }
    if(state==GKPlayerConnectionState.StateUnknown){
        println("unknown")
    }
    println(player.displayName)
    if(state == GKPlayerConnectionState.StateDisconnected){
        if(player.playerID == GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID){
            Label.text = "You Disconnected"
        }
        else{
            Label.text = "Your opponent disconnected"
        }
    }


}
```

What happens is that if one player goes into control center, and turns on airplane mode, it returns that the opponent has disconnected. Is there any way to fix this?

Any feedback will be very appreciated

Comment: What is the behavior you want? If someone disconnects from your server, I think displaying that they disconnected is appropriate.

Comment: What is happening that when someone disconnects from the internet and therefore from game center, game center says that their opponent disconnected and not them

Comment: The call to GKLocalPlayer is probably returning something other than the actual local player due to the disconnection then. When the user connects or reconnects, can you store that value separately so you can confirm it?

Comment: I checked that by printing the player's name, and it was the opponent that it thought disconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, I thought that since bringing up control center didn't call the app delegate applicationDidEnterBackground function that the application was still running while in control center, but it turns out that control center puts it in an inactive state, so I was able to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the iOS Reachability code.

`didChangeConnectionState` is only called for remote connections. If you disconnect (either but entering airplane mode, or legitimately losing WIFI connection) then the connection to the game is broken and `didChangeConnectionState` is called passing in the opponent player.

Using the reachability code you can query whether you're offline when this callback fires. You can then tell that callback is firing because you're offline, as opposed to opponent has lost connection.

A small wrinkle is that sometimes the Reachability call will take a short while to evaluate, allowing the `didChangeConnectionState` call to return first. To allow for this, allow a few seconds after the `didChangeConnectionState` call has fired, then check your reachability results.

Steve.